# Add a rectangle to the center of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, rectangles

I'm trying to draw a `Rectangle` to the center of a `JPanel`. I have made this code but when I run it, the rectangle does not appears in the panel. If I try with `JFrame`, the rectangle appears.  Can someone help me?

### `RectangleTester`

```
package eventi5;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RectangleTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rectangle");
        frame.setSize(250, 250);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final RectangleComponent component = new RectangleComponent();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        panel.add(component);
        frame.add(panel);
    }
}
```

### `RectangleComponent`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RectangleComponent extends JPanel{

    private Rectangle box;

    public RectangleComponent(){
        box=new Rectangle(10,20,30,40);
    }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
        g2.draw(box);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.fill(box);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You might need to set your `RectangleComponent`'s preferred size to have it take up an appropriate amount of space in its container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You need override `getPreferredSize()` of `RectangleComponent` like next:

```
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(box.width+box.x*2,box.height+box.y*2);
    }
```

2) call `super()` method of `paintComponent()`( `super.paintComponent(g);`) before your customizations.

EDIT:

```
public class RectangleComponent extends JPanel {

        private List<Rectangle> boxes;
        private int width = 30;
        private int height = 40;
        private int startX = 10;
        private int startY = 20;

        public RectangleComponent() {
            boxes = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                boxes.add(new Rectangle(startX+(width+startX)*i, startY, width, height));
            }
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++){
                g2.draw(boxes.get(i));
            }
            g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++){
                g2.fill(boxes.get(i));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(boxes.size()*(width+startX)+startX, height+startY*2);
        }

    }
```

Comment: how i can do if i want to draw another Rectangle in the same JPanel?